# Java Priority Queue in Linked List Test Cases

Tags: java, testing, linked-list, nodes, priority-queue

So I'm trying to implement a priority queue with a linked list. I think I have the basics together, but for some reason my test cases aren't working. When I run it, the size show up fine, but none of the node values are showing (only an arrow "->" pops up once). If anyone could help me figure out why it isn't working, or suggest a better way to set up test cases in java (I've never done that before) it would be appreciated!

Node class:

```
public class Node {     //Node class structure

    int data;   //data contained in Node; for assignment purposes, data is an int
    Node next;  //pointer to Next Node

    //Node Constructor
    public Node(int data) {    
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    //Set Methods
    public void setData(int data) {         //set Node value
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {        //set next Node value
        this.next = next;
    }   

    //Get Methods
    public int getData() {                  //get Node value
        return this.data;
    }   
    public Node getNext() {                 //get next Node value
        return this.next;
    }

    //Display the Node Value
    public void displayNode() {
        System.out.println(data + "urgh");  //display value as a string
    }
}
```

Linked List Class:

```
import Question1.Node;

//basic set-up of a FIFO singly linked list
public class SLList{

    protected Node head;    //head of SLList
    protected Node tail;    //tail of SLList
    int n;      //number of elements in SLList

    //SLList constructor
    public SLList() {
        head = null;
        n = 0;
    }   

    //check if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    //return the size of the list
    public int size() {
        return n;           
    }

    //add a new node to the end of the list
    public boolean insert(int x){
        Node y = new Node(x);

        if (head == null){  //if head is null, thus an empty list
            head = y;       //assign head as y
        }
        else{               //if there is already a tail node
            tail.next = y;  //assign the tail's pointer to the new node
        }
        tail = y;           //assign tail to y
        this.n++;           //increment the queue's size
        return true;        //show action has taken place
    }

    //remove and return node from head of list
    public Node remove(){
        if (n == 0){            //if the list is of size 0, and thus empty
            return null;        //do nothing
        }
        else{                           //if there are node(s) in the list
            Node pointer = head;        //assign pointer to the head
            head = head.next;           //reassign head as next node,               
            n--;                        //decrement list size
            return pointer;             //return the pointer
        }       
    }

    //display SLList as string
    public void displayList() {
        Node pointer = head;

        while (pointer != null) {
            pointer.displayNode();
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Priority Queue Class:

```
import Question1.Node;
import Question1.SLList;

public class PriorityQueue extends SLList {

    private SLList list;        //SLList variable

    public PriorityQueue(){     //create the official SLList
        list = new SLList();
    }

    //add a new node; new add method that ensures the first element is sorted to be the "priority"
    public boolean add(int x){
        Node y = new Node(x);

        if (n == 0){        //if there are 0 elements, thus an empty list
            head = y;       //assign head as y
        }
        else if (y.data < head.data){   //if new node y is the smallest element, thus highest priority
            y.next = head;              //assign y's next to be current head of queue
            head = y;                   //reassign head to be actual new head of queue (y)
        }
        else{               //if there is already a tail node
            tail.next = y;  //assign the tail's pointer to the new node
        }
        tail = y;           //assign tail to y
        n++;                //increment the queue's size
        return true;        //show action has taken place
    }

    //delete the minimim value (highest priority value) from the queue and return its value
    public Node deleteMin(){
        return list.remove();       //the list is sorted such that the element being removed in indeed the min
    }

    //return the size of the queue
    public int size() {
        return n;           
    }

    //display Queue as string
    public void displayQueue() {
        System.out.println("->");
        list.displayList();
    }
}
```

Test Cases (so far, the delete one wasn't working so it's commented out):

```
import Question1.PriorityQueue;

public class TestQ1 {           //Test code

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PriorityQueue PQueue1 = new PriorityQueue();

        PQueue1.add(3);
        PQueue1.add(2);
        PQueue1.add(8);
        PQueue1.add(4);

        System.out.println("Test add(x): ");
        PQueue1.displayQueue();
        System.out.println("Test size(): " + PQueue1.size());

        PriorityQueue PQueue2 = new PriorityQueue();
        //Node node1 = PQueue1.deleteMin();

        System.out.println("Test deleteMin():");
        PQueue2.displayQueue();
        System.out.println("Test size(): " + PQueue2.size());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Small tip: by convention, you should instead name your `display` methods, `toString()`.

Comment: For testing your code, you'll generally want to rely on assertions, rather than printing text to the console. Have a look at the JUnit testing framework (the standard Java testing strategy), and try some examples with that.

Answer (score 0):

Change `list.displayList()` to `displayList()`, and you'll see the expected output.

---

Why? Because your queue *is already a list* (that is, an instance of `SLList`). When a class `A` *extends* another class `B`, an instance of `A` is also an instance of `B`. This is *inheritance*.

You've also included an instance variable `private SLList list` within your `PriorityQueue` implementation, which is an example of *composition*. Generally you'll only do one or the other of these two options, depending on your situation. In this case it seems you're trying to use inheritance, so there's no reason to create a separate `list` instance variable. You're adding the data directly to the queue (using the fact that, intrinsically, it is a list in its own right).

You should remove the `list` instance variable, and all the usages of it should refer to the parent class' methods or variables.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason why your `deleteMin` method wasn't working is because that was also referring to that wayward `list` variable. You'll have to use the `tail` variable for that. Give it a try!

Comment: The initial change with displayList helped, yay! For the second part however, I took out the "private SLList list" line but then it rendered the rest of my "list" variables incorrect. What should I change in addition to that line?

Comment: @MandyLB Since `PriorityQueue` extends `SLList`, all of the (visible) methods from `SLList` are available in `PriorityQueue` as well. So in the same way that you can call `displayList` directly, you can also call `size` directly (there's no need to define it again in `PriorityQueue`), and any other methods you need from `SLList` are available as well. What else do you think needs to be changed? :)